# How to use PHP/HTML as interface and Java/Python as function in background?

Tags: java, php, python, html, desktop-application

I'm thinking about writing a desktop application that the GUI is made with either HTML or PHP, but the functions are run by a separate Java or python code, is there any heads up that I can look into?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible options:

1. Run your backend code as an embedded HTTP-server (like Jetty* for Java or Tornado* for Python). If the user starts the application, the backend runs the server and automatically starts the web browser with the URL of your server. This, however, may cause problems with the operating system firewall (running a server on the local machine)
2. You could also have a look at [CEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) (chromium embedded framework). It is made for exactly this purpose (running an HTML-Application inside your code). It uses the same codebase as the chromium (and chrome) web browser. It was developed originally for C++, but there is also a Java binding: [java-cef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef)

Oh and by the way, PHP is a server-side language. I would not recommend to use it in your scenario (since your backend code is Python or Java).

*I have not enough reputation to add more than two links, so you'll have to google those ones yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose data from Java or Python as JSON via GET request and use PHP to access it. There are multiple libraries for each of these languages both for writing and reading JSON. GET request can take parameters if needed.